# VS ReportViewer - Multiple 1xN relationship

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer

I'm learning how to work on ReportView.

How to proceed when I have a table with multiple 1xN relationship ?

I don't want to show the value that is stored on the DataSet field, I want to resolve it to another table.

I know I could do it from Join command on the DataSet, but I have lots of 1xN fields, so I think it isn't practical, the SQL command would be huge and complex.

Thought about using an pre-processed List of object as DataSource. Don't know if its the right way..

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks.